# How to add Ion to an Android project?

Tags: android

I am trying an example from https://github.com/koush/ion to use **Ion** for downloading files.

But unfortunately I do not know how should I add Ion to my project. Should I download it to the android studio folder? If so how should I do it? I really appreciate explanation in details.

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3

Build #AI-162.4069837, built on June 6, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

on windows 10 and I can not change it to any newer version.

Please excuse me if my question is trivial, I am very new to Android and Android studio and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction below, solved my issue

In build.gradle(module:app) in `dependencies` add:

```
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6
```

and in build.gradle(project:XXX) where XXX is the name of the project in `dependencies` add:

```
classpath 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
```

Of course I am using a specific version of Android studio with a custom SDK. So my solution might not work for every one!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the library in your `build.gradle`

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:(insert latest version)'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it but now I got this error: Failed to resolve :   com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:(insert latest version)

Comment: compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:3.1.0 add 3.1.0 instead of (insert latest version)

Comment: post your build.gradle above so we can see

Comment: some one helped me to correct the issue. I am going to post the solution. Thanks any way.